# Access-Control-Allow-Origin angular

Tags: angular, http

Helo I have an update function in my app. but it doesn't update, it shows the following error.

Failed to load http:// localhost:8080/../update: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: //localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}.

i tried a chrome extension to enable acess control, but then i can't view my data at all.

I'm working locally.

Problem solved : It was a problem with the HttpClient.put(url) method. I don't know exactly the reason, but post method worked fine!

Comment: This is a server Issue not an Angular issue. You need to figure out how to setup CORS on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Preflight requests  are a security measurement by explorers, there are a  couple of ways to bypass it.

**Not Recommended** 
Change your backend code so it will accept requests from all origins. (this can lead to some vulnerabilities and you probably have to change it back whenever you want to deploy your code)

**Recommended** 
You can proxy your requests.
If you are using angular CLI this is really easy, just follow [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md). Although it shouldn't be a problem if you are using other technologies.

Comment: But i can already acess to my back end and add read or delete without any problem. how can it just be in the update

Comment: @Mou It probably has something to do with the add-on you are using. I really recommend that you take a look at angular cli proxy doc.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is in your backend.**
It's not accepting cross origin request. If you are using spring use `@CrossOrigin` annotation in controller. If not, figure out to enable cross origin.

Comment: Also can use other crud operations. it just the update that generates that error

Comment: also just @CrossOrigin is fine . you dont need to mention origins